# Como desabilitar o cache de query no MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Quando usamos o comando `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_query_cache'` podemos ver se o cache está habilitado ou não.

Resultado:

```
Variable_name    | Value
----------------------------
have_query_cache | YES
```

Como fazer para desabilitar essa diretiva? Existe algum comando para que eu possa desabilitar o cache automático de queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `query_cache` é dividido em três tipos: Ligado, desligado e sob demanda.

- Desligado: `query_cache_type = 0`
- Ligado para todas as query’s: `query_cache_type = 1`
- Ligado sobre demanda: `query_cache_type = 2`

Para alterar o valor você pode executar o seguinte comando:

```
 SET SESSION query_cache_type=0;
```

ou

```
SET GLOBAL query_cache_type=OFF;
```

Você pode utilizar o [SQL_NO_CACHE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-in-select.html) para usar em uma consulta específica. Ficaria assim:

`SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM table.`

E para usar o cache basta usar o [SQL_CACHE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-in-select.html).

`SELECT SQL_CACHE * FROM table.`

Referências:

- [Query cache configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-configuration.html)
- [Disable query cache](http://makandracards.com/makandra/780-mysql-disable-query-cache-for-database-profiling)
- [optimizar consultas MySQL](https://pt.blog.marceloaltmann.com/optimizar-consultas-em-mysql-com-querycache/)
- [Usando cache](https://www.oficinadanet.com.br/artigo/mysql/usando_o_cache_de_consultas_no_mysql)